# Recursion not executing properly (Used the debugger to trace the output)

Tags: java, recursion

I have used the debugger to trace the execution. It goes deeper and deeper for first if condition until it returns the whole function. It doesn't even go inside second "if" condition which it should go as per my knowledge of recursion

Below is the snippet of my code
please note:

```
n=22
m=7
array = 0000110000111101000101
checker[] = false
```

The code

```
public static boolean ultra(int step)
{
    System.out.println(step);
    if(step>n)
    {
         System.out.println("success1");

         win=true;

         return true;
   }
   else if (step+m>n-1)
   {
        System.out.println("success2");

        win=true;

        return true;
   }
   else if(step<0)
   {
        return false;
   }
   else
   {
        try
        {
             if(array[step+m]==0 && checker[step+m]==false)
             {
                 System.out.println("jump");
                 checker[step+m]=true;
                 return ultra(step+m);
             }
            System.out.println("print "+step);

            if(array[step+1]==0 && checker[step+1]==false)
            {
                System.out.println("forward");

                checker[step+1]=true;
                return ultra(step+1);
             }
             if(array[step-1]==0 && checker[step-1]==false)
             {
                 System.out.println("backward");

                 checker[step+-1]=true;
                 return ultra(step-1);
             }
             else
             {
                 System.out.println("defeat");

                 return false;
             }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            return false;


        }



    }



}
```

When I call `ultra(0)`, I get following output:

```
"0"
"jump"
"7"
"jump"
"14"
"print 14"
"defeat"
```

So basically, recursion is not going into the second if condition. It doesn't even print "print + step" for the first level. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Try stepping through the code using a debugger.

Comment: Hey, I have updated the question. I did that already.

Comment: And at what point did the behavior deviate from what you expect, and what were the variable values at that point that were incorrect?  Please help us help you.

Comment: `checker[] = false` makes no sense.  Do you mean that all the values in the array `checker` are `false`?

Comment: I have a feeling this is something to do with scope. Since ultra only takes 1 parameter, steps which equals 0, and the n is not inside the function itself, which shouldn't matter as long as its in the global space, and doesn't change. Are the 4 lines above the function definition part of the code?

also, what is your code suppose to do? What are you expecting? We cannot help without knowing what the problem you are trying to tackle.

Comment: you have mentioned what you have got. but also tell us want you want. it will help get answerts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its not going to `System.out.println("\tprint " + step)` at the first level because before it reaches that instruction the following block gets executed

```
if (array[step + m] == 0 && checker[step + m] == false) {
                    System.out.println("\tjump");
                    checker[step + m] = true;
                    return ultra(step + m);
                }
```

because you have a return statement within it, it never executes the lines after it.

More over handling an exception is important but consuming the exception is very bad. your sysout does not tell you where the exception occurred and it becomes increasingly hard for some to trace in large code.

```
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e.toString());
    return false;  
}
```

a btter solutions would be to use printStackTrace() on the error object to debug.

```
catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace(); 
    return false;
}
```